# React native camera - default preview seem's zoomed on IOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using React Native Camera for my app, and I'm facing a strange problem.

Here's my code :

```
<View flex>
    <RNCamera ref={ref=> { this.camera = ref; }} style={{flex : 1}} type={this.state.cameraType} flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on} permissionDialogTitle={'Autorisation de l\'appareil photo'} permissionDialogMessage={'Nous avons besoin de votre permission pour accéder à l\'appareil photo.'} zoom={0} ratio={'16:9'} focusDepth={0} />
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', width: 75, height: 75, top: this.state.currentHeight / 2.2, bottom: 0, right: 37, zIndex: 1 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity centerH onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}>
            <Image style={{ width: 75, height: 75 }} source={{ uri: "cameraButton" }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', width: 50, height: 50, top: this.state.currentHeight / 2.9, bottom: 0, right: 50, zIndex: 1, backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: 100 / 2, }}>
        <View flex center>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ ()=> { this.setCameraType() } }>
                <Image style={{ width: 35, height: 35 }} resizeMode="contain" source={{ uri: "camera-flip" }} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', width: 95, height: 75, top: this.state.currentHeight / 1.1, bottom: 0, right: 30, zIndex: 1 }}>
        <View flex center>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ ()=> { this.props.modalManager('camera') } }>
                <Text bigText style={{ color: "white", fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Annuler</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

The aim is to put a preview camera image taking all the screen size (using flex)
My preview is working fine, but the image look a bit zoomed compared to the default IOS camera.
Do you know if there's something I can do ?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm seeing something similar in a react web app that uses the camera when on mobile.